# Как сохранить файл .txt в папку, а если папки не существует создать ее в питоне

Tags: python

Как сохранить файл .txt в папку, а если папки не существует создать ее в питоне. Нужно реализовать простенькую программу с модулем os

Comment: Так проверь папку на существование папку по заданному пути с помощью `os.path.listdir`. Если ее нет, то создай ее с помощью `os.makedirs`. А дальше с помощью `open` открой файл для записи или добавления. Даже если его еще нет, он будет создан

Answer (score 2):

Данный ответ предполагает новую версию python (как минимум 3.4). Вместо модуля `os` имеется также объектно-ориентированная `pathlib`. Ее использование в новых версиях python более предпочтительно.
Код с использованием `pathlib`:

```py
def create_file_inside_of_dir(dirname: str, filename: str):
    dirname = Path(dirname)
    dirname.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    open(dirname / filename, 'a')
```

Преимущество такого варианта состоит в его большей функциональности: можно создать вложенные папки, просто указав желаемый вложенный путь, а не создавая папки последовательно. Пример:

```py
create_file_inside_of_dir('test_dir/another_test_dir/and_another_one', 'text.txt')
```

Это создаст 3 вложенные друг в друга папки и файл в последней.

Answer (score 1):

Как я уже описал в комментариях, для этой задачи нужен только модуль os:

```py
import os


def create_file_inside_of_dir(dirname: str, filename: str):
    os.makedirs(dirname, exist_ok=True)
    open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), 'a')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_file_inside_of_dir('test_dir', 'text.txt')
```